# Convert SharePoint file object into hex string

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, attachments

I am trying to convert sharepoint attachment into hexadecimal string and push it to SQL via powershell.
How can we convert sharepoint file/document into hex in CSOM / Powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer for this. I need this to send attachment from SharePoint list item to SQL in varbinary(MAX) field.
Converted file into ByteArray and then converted it to string

```
$fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Context,$Attachment.ServerRelativeUrl);
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$fileByteStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($fileByteStream)
$fileByteArray = $fileByteStream.ToArray()
$hexString = ($fileByteArray|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join ''
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `Format-Hex` utility to display a file as hexadecimal.

**Syntax**:

```
Format-Hex
      -InputObject <psobject>
      [-Encoding <Encoding>]
      [-Count <long>]
      [-Offset <long>]
      [-Raw]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Reference**: [Format-Hex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex)

Comment: How can we pass Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File object to 'Format-Hex'

Comment: or which object I need to pass as input this .

Comment: `-InputObject` parameter supports certain scalar types(mentioned in the documentation link given in my answer). You may need to convert the file in binary before using Format-Hex.